# PYZMQ REQ-REP Multiple Clients ZMQError with Polling

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, polling, pyzmq

With a **REQ-REP** pattern, I am trying to request multiple `clients` with a timeout using poll, so that if the `server` detects that it is not able to receive a message from the first `client`, it will timeout and move on to the next `client`.

But it seems like after the initial timeout, it is unable to send the next message to the second `client`.

I am getting this error `zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state` on this line `socket.send_string("Sensor Data")` in `server`.

**Full output**:

```
Connecting to machine...
Successfully connected to machine 127.0.0.1:9999
Successfully connected to machine 127.0.0.1:9998
Sending request  0 ...
Machine did not respond
Sending request  1 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tobiw\Documents\Python\Raspberry Pi\zmq\REQrep\testSIMPLEpoll.py", line 16, in <module>
    socket.send_string("Sensor Data")
  File "C:\Users\tobiw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyzmq-17.0.0b3-py3.6-win32.egg\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 541, in send_string
    return self.send(u.encode(encoding), flags=flags, copy=copy, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tobiw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyzmq-17.0.0b3-py3.6-win32.egg\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 384, in send
    return super(Socket, self).send(data, flags=flags, copy=copy, track=track)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 727, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 771, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 249, in zmq.backend.cython.socket._send_copy
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 244, in zmq.backend.cython.socket._send_copy
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 25, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
    raise ZMQError(errno)
zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state
[Finished in 5.3s with exit code 1]
```

**Server**:

```
import zmq
import json

ports = ["127.0.0.1:9999", "127.0.0.1:9998"]

context = zmq.Context()
print("Connecting to machine...")
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
for port in ports:
    socket.connect("tcp://%s" % port)
    print("Successfully connected to machine %s" % port)

for request in range(len(ports)):
    print("Sending request ", request, "...")
    socket.send_string("Sensor Data")  # <-- error occurs here

    # use poll for timeouts:
    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)

    socks = dict(poller.poll(5 * 1000))

    if socket in socks:
        try:
            msg_json = socket.recv()
            sens = json.loads(msg_json)
            response = "Sensor: %s :: Data: %s :: Client: %s" % (sens['sensor'], sens['data'], sens['client'])
            print("Received reply ", request, "[", response, "]")
        except IOError:
            print("Could not connect to machine")
    else:
        print("Machine did not respond")
```

**Client**:

```
import zmq
import time
import json

port = "9998" # multiple similar clients but just with different ports

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

while True:
    #  Wait for next request from server
    message = str(socket.recv(), "utf-8")
    print("Received request: ", message)
    time.sleep(1)
    msgDict = {
        'sensor': "6",
        'data': "123456789",
        'client': "9876",
    }
    msg_json = json.dumps(msgDict)
    socket.send_string(msg_json)
```

If the `server` was able to receive a message from the first `client`, the second `send` to the second `client` will work fine, but if the `server` was **not** able to receive a message from the first `client`, then the error is reproduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foremost, `zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state` in a **REQ-REP** pattern is an indication that the order of `send -> recv -> send -> recv` is not in order. For my case, because of the poll on receive in the `for-loop` there was no final `recv` on the **REQ server** side as it timed out. When the method looped back, it went to `send` again which resulted in `send -> recv -> send -> timeout -> send`. A double `send` scenario which is illegal.

**What I did to rectify it**:
I switched from a **REQ-REP** pattern to a **DEALER-REP** pattern. This gives me an asynchronous server that can talk to multiple **REP** clients.

With `client` staying the same, this is the new `server` for those who are interested:

**Server**:

```
import zmq
import json

ports = ["127.0.0.1:9999", "127.0.0.1:9998"]

context = zmq.Context()
print("Connecting to machine...")
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
for port in ports:
    socket.connect("tcp://%s" % port)
    print("Successfully connected to machine %s" % port)

for request in range(len(ports)):
    print("Sending request ", request, "...")
    socket.send_string("", zmq.SNDMORE)  # delimiter
    socket.send_string("Sensor Data")  # actual message

    # use poll for timeouts:
    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)

    socks = dict(poller.poll(5 * 1000))

    if socket in socks:
        try:
            socket.recv()  # discard delimiter
            msg_json = socket.recv()  # actual message
            sens = json.loads(msg_json)
            response = "Sensor: %s :: Data: %s :: Client: %s" % (sens['sensor'], sens['data'], sens['client'])
            print("Received reply ", request, "[", response, "]")
        except IOError:
            print("Could not connect to machine")
    else:
        print("Machine did not respond")
```